# How to increase the thickness of the line chart?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I see simple example from demos:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/charts/Line.html

How to increase the thickness of the line chart ( not marker) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define style in series config as below

```
   style : { 
            'stroke-width': 2, // set desired value here
        }
```